# DeviceMetrics reporting lower resolution than actual pixels - Android 11 (poss Samsung only)

Tags: java, android, screen-resolution, android-11

DeviceMetrics reports a lower resolution than the actual device pixels. An example is S10 Lite is 1080 pixels wide, but DeviceMetrics reports 810 pixels.

This must be some low resolution mode being selected by the OS. Prior to Android 11 the app has always been returned the full screen width.
How do I convince Android 11 to give the app full resolution, and report back the full screenwidth? Some special manifest attribute, or use/avoidance of certain APIs? (I’ve tried ‘supports-screens’ which is old-school, but that didn’t help)

- compileSdkVersion 30
- targetSdkVersion 30
- minSdkVersion = 14 - 19 depending on the specific app. Tried higher min, but didn't help.
- All reports have been from Samsung users, but that just may be that Pixel phones and other Android 11 devices are currently rare. Tested on S10 Lite, also reported on S20, Note 20.
- The app is stable, several years old, and kept up to date